# HTML Table to CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I’m trying to recreate this sort of layout:

[image: A picture of two phones sits to the left of a content area, consisting of a blurb, and below the blurb, two buttons.]

This is the code I’m currently using to accomplish it:

```
<table style="border:0px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="border:0px;">
            <td><img src="twophones.jpg" alt="" /></td>
            <td>
                <table style="border:0px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr width="100%" style="border:0px;">
                            <td width="100%">

                                <center>
                                    <h11>DISCOVER THE BRANDS AND STYLES DESIGNED FOR YOU</h11>
                                    <br>
                                    <h33>Coming soon to the App Store and Google Play.</h33>

                                    <table style="border:0px; width:410px;">
                                        <tr style="border:0px;"><td style="border:0px;"><img src="dot.png"></td></tr>
                                        <tr style="border:0px;" width="410">
                                            <td style="border:0px;"><a href="#"><img src="app.jpg" alt="" /></a></td>
                                            <td><a href="#"><img src="android.jpg" alt="" /></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </center>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, I’m sick of maintaining this table gunk. How can I maintain the same layout, but using standard CSS techniques?

Here are a couple of my attempts:

```
<div id="parent">       <div id="viewport">
        <a href="#">
<img src="twophones.jpg" style="float:left;>        <img src="twophones.jpg" alt="" />
<h11 style="width:100%;float:right; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">DISCOVER THE BRANDS AND STYLES DESIGNED FOR YOU</h11>
<span><h11>DISCOVER THE BRANDS AND STYLES DESIGNED FOR YOU</h11><br>
<h33>Coming soon to the App Store and Google Play.</h33>
<br>         
<h33 style="width:100%;float:right; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">Coming soon to the App Store and Google Play.</h33>        
        </span>
        </a>
</div>      </div>

<div id="parent">       <div id="parent">
<img src="twophones.jpg" style="float:left;">       <img src="twophones.jpg"     style="float:left;>
<div style="width:65%;float:right;">        <div style="width:65%;float:right;">
<h11>DISCOVER THE BRANDS AND STYLES DESIGNED FOR YOU</h11>
<h11>DISCOVER THE BRANDS AND STYLES DESIGNED FOR YOU</h11>
<br>        <br>
<h33>Coming soon to the App Store and Google Play.</h33>
<h33>Coming soon to the App Store and Google Play.</h33>
</div>      </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _changing it to CSS_? The CSS is there, but inline.

Comment: I mean like removing all the <table> out of it... making it an all CSS table.

Comment: Hopefully this will help you get started - [Here is a bare bones example](http://jsbin.com/cevek/1/edit).

Answer (score 4):

First thing you want do to when doing a layout with CSS is, well, not touching the CSS and dealing purely with the content.  How *best* could we represent this content?  I think this includes all the content rather semantically:

```html
<section>
    <img src="twophones.jpg" alt="">
    <h2>Discover the brands and styles designed for you</h2>
    <p>Coming soon to the App Store and Google Play</p>
    <ul>
        <li class="iphone">
            <a href="#">
                Available on the
                <strong>App Store</strong>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="android">
            <a href="#">
                Available on the
                <strong>Android Market</strong>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

It contains all the content, but it doesn’t look great.  It looks sort of [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/znkx7uoa/embedded/result,html/):

> (picture of two phones)
>
> ### Discover the brands and styles designed for you
>
> Coming soon to the App Store and Google Play
>
> - [Available on the **App Store**](http://www.example.com/)
> - [Available on the **Android Market**](http://www.example.com/)

Your layout doesn’t quite look like that.  First big difference is that nothing’s centered here, but that’s trivial to fix:  ([take a look](http://jsfiddle.net/znkx7uoa/1/embedded/result,html,css/))

```css
section {
    text-align: center;
}
```

And what about those buttons?  Well, each one functions sort of as a blocky part of the page, but we still want it to be inline, so we’ll apply a `display` of `inline-block`.  Furthermore, we want the bolded part to be on another line, so we’ll set its `display` to `block`, which should force that.  Lastly for now, we know it’s got a orangish background and border, and looks like it’s got a little shadow on the text, so [putting all this together](http://jsfiddle.net/znkx7uoa/2/embedded/result,html,css/):

```css
section li a {
    display: inline-block;
    background: orange;  /* fallback for browsers that
                            don't support gradients */
    background: linear-gradient(#f9a60d, #f37111);
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 -1px 0 black;
    border: 1px solid #e79d48;
    border-top-color: #ffe37d;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 0 #a95511;
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;  /* no underlines on our link, please */
    text-align: left;  /* within the button, left-aligned */
}
section li a strong {
    display: block;
}
```

Nice buttons!  But we could still use some icons on them—fortunately, that’s easy: just add a little more padding on the left and apply a background image: ([try it](http://jsfiddle.net/znkx7uoa/3/embedded/result,html,css/))

```css
section li a {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
section li.iphone a {
    background: orange url(iphone-icon.png) no-repeat 10px 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#f9a60d, #f37111), url(iphone-icon.png) no-repeat 10px 10px;
}
/* similar for Android */
```

Now how do you get the buttons to appear in a line?  Fortunately, that’s simple.  First, remove any margins and padding on the list, then make each item `inline-block` ([try it](http://jsfiddle.net/znkx7uoa/4/embedded/result,html,css/)):

```css
section ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
section li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Now how about that image on the side?  It turns out CSS has us covered.  We just tell it we want to float it to the left.  As a common trick, we’ll also set an `overflow: hidden` on the container, so the float is entirely contained within the container.  (You can’t see it standalone, but you may see the effect if you try to embed it in a larger web page.)

```css
section {
    overflow: hidden;
}
section img {
    float: left;
}
```

[Try it](http://jsfiddle.net/znkx7uoa/5/embedded/result,html,css/).  Then we have just one minor visual tweak: we want the header to be uppercased.  Fortunately, CSS has us covered there, too!  Just apply

```css
section h2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

And [we’re done](http://jsfiddle.net/znkx7uoa/6/embedded/result,html,css/).  Of course, there’s more you could do: adjust the margins and/or padding to change the spacing; change the font if necessary, etc., etc., but I’ve explored a few techniques that are generally applicable:

- **Floats** are used and abused all the time in CSS.  They’re useful.
- **Changing `display`** can be useful to force elements to display in or out
  of a line.
- Playing with **`background`** can put icons on things.

I don’t mean for this to be a huge code dump; rather, I’d hope you’d learn something out of it, and be able to do similar things yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can go any more in-depth or explain anything better than the [fantastic answer by icktoofay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25223837/2930477), but here is a simple layout that could also get you started.

[Here is the demo.](http://jsbin.com/cevek/2/edit)

Let's start with the basic HTML layout:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://www.placehold.it/400X500" />
    </div>

    <div class="information">
        <h1>DISCOVER THE BRANDS AND STYLES DESIGNED FOR YOU</h1>

        <h2>Coming soon to the App Store and Google Play.</h2>

        <a class="storeLinks">Play store</a>

        <a class="storeLinks">APP store</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now let's add in some CSS to layout your HTML elements. In this example:

1. `display: table-cell;` can be used to vertically align our content in conjunction with `vertical-align: middle;` and place our image to the left of the text.
2. `html,body { height: 100%; }` allows us to give our wrapping `.wrap` `div` a height of 100% so that all the content contained within `<div class="wrap">` can be vertically centered.
3. `.wrap > div` will target only the `div`s that are directly after `<div class="wrap">`.
4. `margin: 0 auto;`, along with a fixed width, keep all our content horizontally centered.

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}    
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}    
.wrap {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}    
.wrap > div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}    
.image {
    width: 400px;
}
.information {
    width: 500px;
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
h2 {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
}
.storeLinks {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #DDD;
    padding: 10px;
}
```